# Special characters encoding during CSV import

Tags: php, csv

I have script that read *.CSV file and then export it content to MSSQL Database. Script is running only via CLI.

My problem is that this CSV file contains string with national characters like `ą,ó,ż,ź,ś`. For example i have word `pracowników` but in CLI i see word `pracownikˇw`.

**My code**

```
$handler = fopen($file, "r");
        if ($handler !== false) {
            while (($this->currentRow = fgetcsv($handler, 0, $this->csvDelimiter)) !== false) {

                $row = $this->setHeaders(
                    $this->currentRow,
                    $this->config[$type]['columnMapping']
                );

                if ($row !== false) {
                    $this->dataImported[$type][] = $row;
                }
            }

            fclose($handler);
        }
```

**What i tried**

- Using `fgetcsv` with `setlocale` or without - not working.
- Replace `fgetcsv` with `fgets` and read each line via `str_getcsv` - not working.
- Using `utf8_encode` for each row - not working.

**Additional info**

- According to my PHP (PHP5.3) and few editors this file is encoded in `ANSII`, i tried to decoded it with `iconv` but all special characters are always replace with some strange symbols, like showed before.

Comment: where does the unwanted conversion happen exactly, when it is read or when it is inserted? I'd expect it to happen on insertion into the database...

Comment: @Jakumi the unwated conversion happend just after file reading

Comment: To *read* it correctly in the CLI change the locale to one that supports those characters with `chcp` but keep in mind it has very limited support for unicode. However perhaps the issue is that you need to set the correct coalition and the encoding for the database if other apps have issues reading it as well.

Comment: @Xorifelse This problem occurred also in database table after insert. It doesn't matter where i check the word, it always has strange symbols instead of national characters. In other hand, if i add something to database via normal html form, all characters are saved properly.

Comment: Open the file in notepad++ or something and save-as a utf-8 document and try again.

Comment: @Xorifelse Problem still exist, just the strange symbols of national characters has changed ;)

Answer (score 1):

On loop of `$this->currentRow` try to use for each element which has special char.

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($data[$c],"HTML-ENTITIES","UTF-8");
```